# MPLAB-X new Assembler

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplabx

I am trying to assemble a old project from old MPASM on this new MPLAB-X Assembler only to end up with many errors and I have searched for usage or help and this seems to be lacking.

Anyone know what the new formats, syntax's etc are for this assembler
eg

```
#IFDEFINE
#ENDIF
ORG
```

defining names : eg `RELAY      equ     GP2`  (Old MPASM)

any other help or link to where this info is would be appreciated.

Comment: Been there, done that...there is a document that helps you to transfer old MPLAB projects to MPLAB-X: https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:migration

Comment: The formats for these should be in the instruction manual. Also look at some example code. In my assembler days #IFDEFINE (If Defined)  #ENDIF (If Not Defined)  ORG (Originate at the specified address).

Comment: look here:https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPASM%20to%20MPLAB%20XC8%20PIC%20Assembler%20Migration%20Guide%2050002973A.pdf

Comment: e.g. `#IFDEFINE`-> `#ifdefine`

Comment: The new mplab is completely incompatible with the old, is a frequent complain…